# prototype.apply() on a function with overloads

Tags: typescript

If I'm trying to extend a function without extending the entire class. 
So, In this `NodeJS http module`, I would like to do redefine the `response.end` function, do my logic, and call the original `response.end` in the end.

The problem is that the end function has 3 overloads. So, I can not apply it with a rest parameter "args". I've tried a union type of all of it's possible arguments tuples, but it still didn't work.

Error's I'm getting:

```
Type '(...args: [any, (string | undefined)?, ((() => void) | undefined)?] |         
    [any, ((() => void) | undefined)?] | [any]) => void' is not assignable to 
    type '{ (cb?: (() => void) | undefined): void; (chunk: any, cb?: (() => 
    void) | undefined): void; (chunk: any, encoding?: string | undefined, cb?: 
    (() => void) | undefined): void; }'.
    Types of parameters 'args' and 'cb' are incompatible.
    Type '[((() => void) | undefined)?]' is not assignable to type '[any, 
    (string | undefined)?, ((() => void) | undefined)?] | [any, ((() => void) | 
    undefined)?] | [any]'.
    Type '[((() => void) | undefined)?]' is not assignable to type '[any]'.
    Property '0' is optional in type '[((() => void) | undefined)?]' but 
    required in type '[any]'.
```

AND

```
Argument of type '[any, (string | undefined)?, ((() => void) | undefined)?] 
    | [any, ((() => void) | undefined)?] | [any]' is not assignable to 
    parameter of type '[any, (string | undefined)?, ((() => void) | 
    undefined)?]'.
    Type '[any, ((() => void) | undefined)?]' is not assignable to type '[any, 
    (string | undefined)?, ((() => void) | undefined)?]'.
    Types of property '1' are incompatible.
    Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | 
    undefined'.
    Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

My current workaround is using the @ts-ignore decorator:

```
const end = res.end;
res.end = function(...args: any[]): void {
    // .....
    res.end = end;

    // @ts-ignore, apply any[] args as end has several overloads
    res.end.apply(this, args);
    // ......
};
```

The code I expect to work is by defining args as a union type of all of the overloads arguments tuples:

```
res.end = function(...args: [any, string?, (() => void)?] | [any, (() => 
                  void)?]): void {
   // my logic ....
   res.end = end;

   res.end.apply(this, args);
   // rest of my logic
 };
```